# Abrir uma view com Codeigniter em uma pagina diferente

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu gostaria de abrir uma view em uma outra aba do navegador  usando o Codeigniter, alguém sabe como fazer?

Na `tag` "a href" uso a propriedade `target=_blank` pra conseguir.

Como faço pra passar essa propriedade no `$this->load->view('nome_view')?`

Answer (score 3):

A forma de fazer isso é como você já fez, usando `target=_blank` no link.

Se você olhar na [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) a única sobrecarga que vai achar do método `view()` é uma para passar um objeto de dados. Não há o que ser feito a nível de Controller para abrir em uma nova guia ou popup. Se você prover mais detalhes do porque precisava disso, posso te dar alguma outra sugestão, provavelmente com Ajax e JavaScript.

Link:

```
<a href="index.php/clientes/inserir" target="_blank">Inserir</a>
```

Controller:

```
class Clientes extends CI_Controller {
   public function inserir() {
      $this->load->view("inserir");
   }
 }
```

Comment: O Murilo está certo. O código php é executado no servidor. Qualquer interação com o navegador, como abrir determinado conteúdo em uma nova aba, usualmente é feito usando javascript, que é executado no cliente.

Comment: Obrigado Murilo pelo suporte, o que estou fazendo é criando um relatório que vai ser mostrado em um pdf, e quando executo o código pra gerar o relatório em pdf ele acaba carregando na mesma aba no navegador e o usuário acabar saindo do sistema, e o que estava querendo é justamente gerar esse pdf em outra aba. Mas, acabei encontrando uma solução, que resolveu por enquanto a minha necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

é possível da seguinte forma:
exemplo:

```
     $atts=array(
      'window_name'=>'_blank'
     );               

     echo anchor_popup('SeuControler/SuaFuncaoQueEncaminhaAPaginaView', 'Pagina de Impressão',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'), $atts );

     ? >
```